# Angular 8 & Firebase AuthGuard still redirecting to login after user logged in

Tags: angular, firebase, angular7, angular8, angular-router-guards

I'm having a trouble on the after logged-in, the links are not working or I cannot access the routes / links and still redirecting me back to the login page. What the correct output should be is I can access all the links / routes after logged-in. Im using firebase as my database

**My Auth Service Type Script**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  user$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(
    public db: AngularFirestore,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router
  ) {    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState;
  }




  login(email: string, password: string){
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
      value => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("loggedIn", email);
        console.log('Success!', value);
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      }
    ).catch(err=>{
      console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
      this.router.navigate(['sign-up']);
    })
  }


  signup(email: string, password: string){
    this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
      value => {
        console.log('Success!', value);
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      }
    ).catch(err=>{
      console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
    })
  }

  logout(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['sign-in']);
  }
}
```

**My AuthGuard Type Script**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor(private authService:AuthService, private router:Router) {

  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')) {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/sign-in'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
    return false;
  }

}
```

**my Routings**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/sign-in', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'books', component: BooksComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'add-book', component: AddBookComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent },
  { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**Finally my LoginComponent**

```
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  email: string;
  password: string;


  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login(){
    this.auth.login(this.email, this.password);
    this.email = this.password = '';
  }

}
```

Thank you. What my output should be is, after I logged-in I can access all the routes that has been guard activated before logged-in

Comment: I see you have stored the item in session storage and validating the value of item from localstorage

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma - ok sir, what am i missing?

Comment: I haven't done a lot of investigation here, but I know that the angular router will route to the first route it matches. Try moving the empty route downwards. Also your route guard's canActivate method can also return a UrlTree. Try using that instead of injecting the router to route.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`, you need choose either, since they are not the same. If you set something in `sessionStorage`, it won't be found in `localStorage`. But I don't really think you need either of them. You have the `authState`, which you can listen to in your authguard. Angularfire also have inbuilt route guards, so you could also consider using that: [AngularFire Guards](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md), but if you want your own guard, I suggest the following:

```ts
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService:AuthService, private router:Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.authService.user$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((user: User) => {
        if (user) {
          return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/sign-in'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

auth.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.afAuth.user.pipe(
      tap(user => {
        if (!user) {
          this.router.navigate([ 'signin' ], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        }
      }),
      map(user => !!user )
    );
  }
}
```

signin.component.ts

```
...
      await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      const returnUrl = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).queryParams.returnUrl;
      this.router.navigate([returnUrl ? returnUrl : 'dashboard']);
...
```

"@angular/core": "~10.1.5",
"@angular/fire": "^6.0.3",